# How many crystal forms of HCl have been identified - where to find the unit cells/lattice constants?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, crystallography

This [blog](https://crystallography365.wordpress.com/2014/03/13/it-is-sitting-in-your-stomach-hydrochloric-acid/) about stomach acid shows this image of the "zig-zag" form of crystalline HCl (see also [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DCl_Neutron_powder.png) where it looks (to me) like <s>five</s> *four* HCl's per unit cell), but links to this [cubic crystal structure](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/9014578.html) (2nd image) data card instead with only one HCl/cell.

I've read crystallographic "data cards" in a past life, but I have no idea how to search for all the forms of HCl on-line (and non-paywalled) now, in order to get the lattice constants, angles, unit cells etc. to build a 3D model of each form of crystalline HCl in [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33480/5334) for example.

*note:* I am really looking for just the dimensions and shape of the unit cell, and coordinates of the atoms within the unit cell *as a name and numbers, as one would find on a crystallographic data card*. I can do all the plotting - no need for plotting software.

---

> [image]

---

> [image]

---

**below:** Here's the Wikipedia image mentioned above, from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DCl_Neutron_powder.png). It certainly looks like the Chlorines are at 0.25 and 0.75 along the *a-axis* (vertically) and 0.00 and 0.50 along the *b-* and *c-axes*, so there seems to be enough information here to work out or infer the complete 3D structure, assuming it's cubic, and further infer that `a=b=c=521pm`, which suggests a density of this solid of about 1.7 g/cm^3. But remember, when you *infer*, you make an *inf* out of *e* and *r*.

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the first picture depicted, I would refrain from stating there are five HCl molecules per unit cell.  One thing, while there is some choice in the definition of *a unitcell* (there are several definitions possible, even under the constrain "it should be the simplest and still complete representation possible"), lower multiplicities occur more often; and more frequently seen values are $Z = 1, 2, 4$.

Second remark, again to the first picture: no, it does not look so as there were five molecules per unit cell.  Here, the projection of the $(a,b)$-plane is depicted (the little green and red axis emerging the origin O bear a label).  To graphically determine the actual multiplicity or the number of molecules present in a unit cell, it is better to "walk around" the unit cell; for example by accessing either *.cif (typical for small molecule structures) or *.pdb (more typical for protein structures) in a appropriate program, like CCDC's [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/) (likely used in the first drawing), or [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/) (used for the second drawing), or [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/).  Each of the three programs may be deployed under Windows, Linux, or MacIntosh; and in terms of displaying structures and to perform measurements of distances and angles available for free (as free beer).

It is possible, yet not in every case necessary to go from *.pdb or *.cif *via* Blender to prepare a dataset for 3D print though.  The "just do it" software that comes to my mind for this purpose is Werner Kaminsky's [cif2vrml](http://cad4.cpac.washington.edu/WinXMorphHome/Cif2VRMLhome/Cif2VRML.htm) (windows only).  If you have Mercury (which actually may read *both* *.pdb, *.cif, beside *.mol, *.mol2, *.xyz, too), there is a built-in file -> print 3D menu, too; allowing you to chose between *.vrml or (then colourless) *.stl file.  Doing so found entry in publications, where examples in the *Journal of Chemical Education* like [DOI: 10.1021/acs.jchemed.5b00597](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jchemed.5b00597) and [DOI: 10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00293](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jchemed.6b00293) come pretty close to what you intend to do. (As you are not afraid of larger molecules, consider the dedicated [NIH 3D exchange](https://3dprint.nih.gov/) as a valuable source of inspiration, too.)  Both jmol as well as Avogadro (referring to 1.2.0; not to the branch of Avogadro2) equally offer VRML export, the former including a dedicated how-to [here](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/3D_printing).

For Jmol (the second figure presented), there are (at least) two options to read *.cif data.  The one by the GUI typically opens the *.cif, representing both the crystallographic motif and the unit cell (the later may be switched off, if necessary / useful).  Note that the GUI in the top row differs slightly from the one accessible by right-mouse-button click *inside* the window.  Via the toprow gui, you may access the *CLI console*, too -- allowing you to access many other functions, too.  For example, if you decompressed the *.zip archive, placed your *.cif into the same directory where jmol.jar lives, typing

> load cell test.cif {1 1 1}

will load the data set, test.cif, and will fill the complete unitcell till indices {1 1 1}. For one of the data found at COD, Jmol provided me this representation:

[image]

Where to get the *.cif? Literature databases like ACS' Scifinder and Elsevier's Reaxys indicate / link to such primary literature.  Depending on the journals policy, these *.cif data may be freely available in the SI (ACS journals, for example), or not (Tetrahedron family ...).  Clearly, a dedicated database ones like [CSD](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/csd/) (organic, metalorganic; preferentially small molecules than proteins) is an option.  For the service and potential insight offered, an annual academic subscription is very well invested money (was once around US$ 300-400 per year and full time equivalent).  If you encounter their structure code in a literature reference, but not the *.cif, you may request the data *free of charge* [here](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/?); regardless if you / your institution holds a subscription, or not.

For mineral compounds, for example [ISCD](https://icsd.fiz-karlsruhe.de/search/index.xhtml;jsessionid=DBBC4C70E587AF3088914B7908BF4C8D) or the one by [AMS](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/AMS/amcsd.php).  The baltic [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/index.php) is much younger than the others (CSD started more than 50 years ago), so the data coverage is not yet this complete, but searchable by [keyword](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/search.html) and [structure](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/jsme_search.html), too; yielding by the former (allowing only H and Cl as the only elements present) 5 entries for HCl.

Where to find *all* the *.cif of HCl? It is not really organic / metallorganic (CSD), nor really a mineral (ISCD).  Perhaps *via* Scifinder and Reaxys one may retrieve a more round answer.

**Addition**

One reference found [doi:10.1038/213171a0](https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v213/n5072/abs/213171a0.html) is based on powder diffraction studies of HCl and DCl, listing these structures known to the authors back in 1967:

[image]

It continues with further powder diffraction studies, presenting an orthorhombic model, with four molecules per unit cell:

[image]

and a projection very similar to your first figure:

[image]

From these two it may be possible to construct (manually) a [*.cif file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallographic_Information_File) which is then readable to Mercury others.  For this nature paper, Thomson Reuter's Web of Science alone knows about 139 citations, the most recent one in 2015 [10.1021/acs.jpcc.5b01653](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpcc.5b01653) about *predicted* supraconducting polymorphs of HCl and HBr in the monoclinic $C2/m$.

Furthermore, a cif file based the Italian 1933 structure report the English wikipedia refers to is accessible in the COD if searching by keyword (H and Cl elements present, excluding O and C, minimal = maximal number of elements = 2).

Comment: Please check what I've written: "see also [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DCl_Neutron_powder.png) where it looks like five HCl's per unit cell" I can change it to "...looks to me like..." but I have a hunch that's... NOPE!  Now it looks like four! :)  $ 4\times \frac{1}{4} \ + \ 4\times\frac{1}{2} \ + 1 $ (counting the chlorine sites in the unit cell shown there).

Comment: @uhoh Initially five, now four ... I'll take a look at it; thanks for your input.

Comment: ...and I'll need a bit of time to take in this very extensive answer as well.

Comment: @uhoh The paper mentioned by you has some limitations, data set based on powder diffraction, not on a single crystal diffraction), which are understandable; Z = 4.  It is cited more than 139 times, as a look into *one* of the literature databases shows.  *Briefly* glancing over *some* abstracts, there are cubic, orthorhombic, monoclinic, triclinic or even disordered structure exp./theo. models, too (http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1743967) around. Further ramifications imaginable, it may dangerously turn into a question put on hold "because to broad" (well, along the parameters used for chemSE).

Comment: Well, I didn't ask how many papers there are, or how many entries there are in data bases. I've just asked *How many crystal forms of HCl have been identified?* If it is not clear to you which are duplicates or which are in error, then your answer should be "I do not know personally", but let's wait and give some others a chance to look at the question before putting it on hold so quickly. It is possible that someone actually knows the answer, or finds a reference where this has been cleared up. I'm guessing the answer is *three* or *two*.

Comment: @uhoh "Currently I am not able to state how many truely different crystal structures of HCl are known, either experimentally, or theory predicts." I sincerly agree with your suggest.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, and also for the additional info from the 1967 paper - for me this is really helpful to go back to the original work - where one can read more about how things were actually being worked out.